# C# Form Popup Menu Behaviour

Tags: c#, forms, focus, popupwindow

Strangely, I can't seem to find the answer to this one.

With a normal `ContextMenuStrip`, when the user right clicks the popup menu opens. If the menu is already open, it opens at the new mouse location.

I wish to implement this same behavior using a form.

If I use `Form.Show()` the form opens, but when the user right clicks and the form is already open, it closes, and requires the user to right click twice.

If I use `Form.ShowDialog()`, the form wont close when it loses focus.

So, how can I show a form on right click, then if the user right clicks again, close the first form and open it again at the new location?

Answer (score 0):

You have to handle some events, suppose you have a main form and a popup form. This popup form should `Owner` set to the main form:

```
PopupForm popup = new PopupForm();
popup.Owner = mainForm;//or this if the code is placed in the MainForm class
//MouseUp event handler for your mainForm
private void mainForm_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e){
  if(e.Button == MouseButtons.Right){
    popup.Location = PointToScreen(e.Location);
    if(!popup.Visible) popup.Visible = true;
  } else if(popup.Visible) {
    popup.Hide();//Don't close, just hide, otherwise you have to handle more...
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but if I need to close the form, what should I handle?

Comment: @Simon do you mean close the main form or the popup form?

Comment: Close the popup form :)